# Keras Subclassing : TypeError: 'KerasTensor' object is not callable Call arguments received by layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Implementing UNet but getting an error: type error 'KerasTensor' object is not callable

```
class UNet(keras.Model):
  """
  argument: input_shape=(572, 572, 1) => default 
  """
  def __init__(self, input_shape=(572, 572, 1), **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    self.maxpool = keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2)
    self.concat = keras.layers.Concatenate() # concats through depth
    self.conv_sz1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=1, padding="same")

  class CONV2_BLOCK(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.filters = filters

    def call(self, inputs):
      x = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters, kernel_size=3, use_bias=False)(inputs)
      x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
      x = keras.layers.Activation(keras.activations.relu)(x)
      x = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters, kernel_size=3, use_bias=False)(x)
      x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
      outputs = keras.layers.Activation(keras.activations.relu)(x)
      return outputs
      

  class CONV_T(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.filters = filters

    def call(self, inputs):  
      outputs = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=self.filters, kernel_size=2, stride=2)(inputs)
      return outputs

  class CROP(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, cropping, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.cropping = cropping

    def call(self, inputs):
      outputs = keras.layers.Cropping2D(cropping=self.cropping)(inputs)
      return outputs      

  def call(self, inputs):
    # self.conv_arr = [64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
    # self.crop_arr = [4, 17, 40, 88] down to up
    x1 = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=64)(self.inputs(inputs))
    x = self.maxpool(x1)

    x2 = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=128)(x)
    x = self.maxpool(x2) 

    x3 = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=256)(x)
    x = self.maxpool(x3) 

    x4 = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=512)(x)
    x = self.maxpool(x4)

    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=1024)(x)

    x = self.concat([self.CONV_T(filters=512)(x), self.CROP(cropping=4)(x4)])
    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=512)(x)

    x = self.concat([self.CONV_T(filters=216)(x), self.CROP(cropping=17)(x3)])
    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=256)(x)

    x = self.concat([self.CONV_T(filters=128)(x), self.CROP(cropping=40)(x2)])
    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=128)(x)

    x = self.concat([self.CONV_T(filters=64)(x), self.CROP(cropping=88)(x1)])
    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=64)(x)

    outputs = self.conv_sz1(x)

    return outputs

test_model = UNet(input_shape=(572, 572, 3))
print(test_model(tf.random.uniform(shape=(2, 572, 572, 3))).shape)
```

but getting error as

```
---> 48     x1 = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=64)(self.inputs(inputs))
     49     x = self.maxpool(x1)
     38
```

> TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'u_net_1' (type UNet).
> 'KerasTensor' object is not callable
> Call arguments received by layer 'u_net' (type UNet):
> • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(2, 572, 572, 3), dtype=float32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when calling `self.inputs(inputs)`,(you can't use input layer in keras subclassing, only for sequential and functional API) but in general you're defining the layers and model wrongly. Here is one way to define a custom `keras.Model` (I've also cleaned up the code a bit and removed duplicated lines):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as tfkl
from functools import partial

class ConvBlock(tfkl.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters: int, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.conv1 = tfkl.Conv2D(filters=int(filters), kernel_size=3, use_bias=False)
        self.bn1 = tfkl.BatchNormalization()
        self.bn2 = tfkl.BatchNormalization()
        self.activation = tf.nn.relu
        self.conv2 = tfkl.Conv2D(filters=int(filters), kernel_size=3, use_bias=False)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.activation(x)

        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)

        outputs = self.activation(x)
        return outputs

class UNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, input_shape=(572, 572, 1), filter_list=(64, 128, 256, 512),
                 crop_values=(4, 17, 40, 88), **kwargs):
        assert len(filter_list) == len(crop_values)

        # pre-define some layers
        max_pool = tfkl.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2)
        concat = tfkl.Concatenate()

        ConvT = partial(tfkl.Conv2DTranspose, kernel_size=2, strides=2)
        Crop = partial(tfkl.Cropping2D)

        # model architecture
        inputs = tfkl.Input(shape=input_shape, name='image')
        x = inputs

        layers = []

        # conv_block -> max-pool
        for filters in filter_list:
            x = ConvBlock(filters=filters)(x)
            layers.append(x)
            x = max_pool(x)

        x = ConvBlock(filters=1024)(x)

        # concat(conv_t, crop) -> conv_block
        for filters, crop, layer in zip(reversed(filter_list), crop_values, reversed(layers)):
            print(filters, crop, layer.shape)
            x = concat([ConvT(filters=filters)(x), Crop(cropping=crop)(layer)])
            x = ConvBlock(filters=filters)(x)

        outputs = tfkl.Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=1, padding='same')(x)

        super().__init__(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, **kwargs)
```

But to make it have matching shapes, I had to change a bit the values you use for the crop layer:

```
unet = UNet(input_shape=(572, 572, 3), crop_values=[4, 16, 40, 88])
print(unet(tf.random.uniform((2, 572, 572, 3))).shape)  # -> TensorShape([2, 388, 388, 2])
```

Lastly, I got an output shape of **`(388, 388, 2)`** is that right for your problem?

Comment: `bn1` and `bn2` are two different instantiations of a batch-normalization layer, they are two *different* objects and you want to do that because each internally keeps statistics of the inputs. Same for `ConvBlock` they are the same set of layers but different instantiations (also with different parameters, i.e. `filters` for example). Basically, the syntax `ConvBlock(filters=...)` creates the instance of type `ConvBlock`, then the second call `(x)`  applies that to the layer `x` returning a symbolic tensor. Have a look at the [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/).

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here. Please, flag them as off-topic and encourage the user to ask them at Stack Overflow or Data Science SE. See our on-topic page for more info.